# Displaying data retrieved from Firebase database specifically

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a database in Firebase.

The structure is:

```
M_Accounts
   atest
      email: "atest@test.com"
      password: "pass1"
   btest
      email: "btest@test.com"
      password: "pass2"
```

I want to retrieve information on a specific user (For example on "atest") and display the information on seperate labels in XCode 8.1 - Swift.

For example I want to display the email on Label1.text and password on Label2.text.

Is there anyway I can do this? I tried and was unsuccessful.

Here is the code I came up with (Im new to XCode - self taught).

The username variable is passed from another form

```
    var username = ""

    //reference to database
    self.dbReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //reference to users in database
    self.usersReference = dbReference.child("M_Accounts").child(username)//.queryOrdered(byChild: "username")

    //data comes into a snapshot object
    self.usersReference.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        //use the keys to get the values

        let email = snapshotValue["email"]
        let password = snapshotValue["password"]

        self.label1.text = email!
        self.label2.text = password!
```

Comment: Inside your observe closure - if you add:  print(snapshot) does it print the atest node?

Comment: Also, you may want to use this format for the Dictionary:  let snapshotValueDictionary = snapshot?.value as! [String: AnyObject]

Comment: The form crashes the moment I run it ( Since the code is in the ViewDidLoad ) 

I get this error


`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:`

@Jay

Comment: Your code 'works', so the issue is your username - it's an empty string in the code you posted (username = "") so it needs to contain a valid key (parent node) name.

Comment: @Jay If that is the case how can I make them display specific user info based on the current logged in user, any suggestions? Since the passing from a previous form wont work.

Comment: What you are really asking is 'how to I read a node from Firebase' and that's covered in the Firebase documentation and getting started guide. The slight difference is that users in Firebase have a uid, so your users node would be structured like this:  /users/uid0, /users/uid1 etc. Then your reference is simply let usersRef = myRootRef.child("users").child(uid_x), and observing that node will read in all of the info about user with uid_x. If you know the users uid (you would know that they authenticate) you can certainly pass it from one view to the next.